# PHP and XSLTProcessor Misbehavior

Tags: php, libxml2, libxslt, xslt

Simple question: Why is a PHP function called from an XSL Stylesheet just returning the last argument passed:

foo.xsl:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="php:function('date','c')" />
</xsl:template>
```

PHP:

```
...  
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsl->registerPHPFunctions();
$xsl->importStylesheet($fooStylesheet);
echo $xsl->transformToXML($myXML);
```

I Get the output

```
c
```

and if I call `<xsl:value-of select="php:function('date')" />` I just get `date` as my output. Seems strange to me.

**Version info:**
PHP 5.3.2
libxslt Version 1.1.26
libxslt compiled against libxml Version 2.7.6
EXSLT   enabled
libexslt Version    1.1.26

Comment: Did you put the PHP namespace in your stylesheet root tag? Like `<stylesheet xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">`

Comment: @zneak - that might help! Answer and get your +10 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the PHP xmlns in your `<stylesheet>` root tag:

```
<stylesheet xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
```

Comment: Fairly straight forward, but I had been starting at that stylesheet for an hour!